# Get launch configurations from vscode extension

Tags: vscode-extensions, launch, vscode-debugger

How can I get all launch configurations?

I considered reading the launch.json file in the .vscode folder, but then I realized that there are some launch configurations that are created dynamically and others that are available without any launch.json file present anywhere. How do I get these configurations?

Comment: Is this for a debug adapter? If so you will get the config passed in to the `resolveDebugConfiguration` method. I can post more details if I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to fetch all the launch configurations:

```
let workspace =  workspace.uri.path;
const config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("launch", workspace);
const configurations = config.get<any[]>("configurations");

if (!configurations) {
    return;
}

configurations.forEach((config) => {
  // read or modify the config
})
```

Comment: As of Jan/2022, the way to retrieve the launch configurations is `const config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('launch', vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri);`; see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration.